# How do I permanently enable the external video card in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I have a Lenovo G50-80 laptop with an on-board Intel HG Graphics 5500 and an external 2048MB ATI AMD Radeon R5 M330, running Windows 10 Pro.

Windows chooses its self when to use one GPU or another. Normally it uses the on-board GPU and it switches to the secondary GPU when I start a game that requires it (I assume it's when some game requires DirectX graphics). Is there a way I can configure Windows to always use the secondary graphics card and ignore the on-board card?

Comment: Is there an option in the driver? With an nvidia card, there is a global setting to use Intel, Nvidia or let Windows choose, in addition to being able to set this for each application.

Comment: "Is there an option in the driver?" - this is what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set default graphics card for your programs:**

1. Right-Click and Open the **Nvidia Control Panel** from the Desktop.
2. Select **Manage 3D Settings** under **3D Settings**.
3. Click on the **Program Settings** tab and select the program you want to choose a graphics card for from the drop down list.
4. And select the **Preferred Graphics Processor** for that specific program from the drop down list.

*and*

[**Set your default graphics card (NVidia)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7DrQmDXHuY)

[image: NVidia]

Comment: I don't have `Nvidia Control Panel` on my Desktop. I only have `Graphics Properties` which opens a program to configure the integrated Intel graphics adapter. I already searched there and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @f.ardelian have you searched in your control panel?

Comment: It's not there. If there was an obvious way to do it, I would have done it. https://i.imgur.com/QXTosIg.png

Comment: @f.ardelian try downloading the latest driver pack from the website...install it and see if it shows up...

Comment: Have you installed the ATI/AMD equivalent control panel? I do not see any Catalyst drivers on your control panel.

Comment: @AG I installed the latest driver and I didn't get Catalyst, but I got Radeon settings. Unfortunately, it won't let me set the entire system to use the AMD GPU for compatibility reasons.